# how to find data into an array mongodb , nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am finding data from an array. that is a course and I want to find out an article by using the title, which is stored into the Course's Articles. I am going step by step...
(1) I want fine the course by the name,
(2) after of it, I want to find an article into course's article by using the title of an article
(3) and render the article and course to the web page
here is code

```
const course = req.params.course
const article_title = req.query.article

Course.findOne({name: course , article:article_title}).then(function(data){
    console.log(data)
    res.render('article',{data :data})
}).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
```

here is DB

```
_id:61c057cfd70f2fb178d4e996
name:"Soft "
 discription:"House"
article:Array
    0:Object
    title:"Where does it come from?"
    content:"<p>Title is very important for an article to explain content | article..."
   _id:61c05d4a3905f61f72a8e61b
    1 :Object
    2:Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search you can use:

```
Couse.findOne({name: course, 'article.title': article_title})
```

So you will get the document with the articles you need.

Using projection and `$elemMatch`, you can filter the article array itself so that only the subdocument you want is there:

```
Couse.findOne({name: course, 'article.title': article_title}, {
   article: {
      $elemMatch: {
         title: article_title
      }
   }
})
```

You can try it in MongoPlayground
https://mongoplayground.net/p/SVXNGE6tuW7